# pattern for input type=“text” with min and max number and with conditional

Tags: javascript

How to write pattern for input `type="text"` (it can't be number and the validation can't be with JS) that allow me to enter only numbers, min:1 and max:30? with some conditional:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox" name="Checkbox" [attr.pattern]="selectedField === 'calendar' ?([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]): false"   [(ngModel)]="periodicObj[0].ischecked"    (change)="OnChange($event,0)">
```

So basically based on selectedField I need to validate my input field

Comment: `the validation can't be with JS` only tag is javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="text" name="someName" id="someId" required="required" pattern="(30|([1-2][0-9])|[1-9])"/>
```

Comment: i'm using Angular 2 so can we do it using Directive but not sure how to communicate Parent form as i'm in child form. Or any another option.

Comment: pattern is a standard HTML5 attribute so it should work independently by the framework you are using.

Comment: but as i told it is  basically based on selectedField and then I need to validate my input field

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Angular2, by the way if you whant to validate the input field via javascript or whatever you can use this regexp to match your string: (30|([1-2][0-9])|[1-9]) contains 3 statements: 30 base match, ([1-2][0-9]) match 2 digit numbers: first from 1 to 2, second from 0 to 9. [1-9] match one digit number from 1 to 9

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use input `type="number`" so it will handle `min` and `max`

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="30" />
```

And without `javascript` how you will `validate` the `value` ?

Comment: because he said it cant be number?

Comment: we can't change it. Is there any alternative to achieve it.

Comment: how to handle it in js?

Comment: If you can do it with js you can change type of textbox to `number`

Comment: ok if i do it Angular Directive then how my form will invalidate.?

Comment: I don't know about `angular` but you can change `type` with javascript